# compiling cocoa lumberjack with Xcode 8.3.2 results in errors in DDOSLogger.m

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoalumberjack

Trying to build cocoa lumberjack/swift via cocoa pods. 
Compiling the latest tag 3.2.0 ends up with errors in DDOSLogger.m 
Here a sample:

```
        .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:68:17: error: static_assert failed "formatters/labels/descriptions must be a constant string"
                os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, msg);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:271:9: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_debug'
        os_log_with_type(log, OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:175:9: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_with_type'
        OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT(_os_log_impl, \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/trace_base.h:59:28: note: expanded from macro 'OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT'
        OS_LOG_PRAGMA_PUSH OS_LOG_STRING(LOG, _os_fmt_str, fmt); \
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/trace_base.h:50:9: note: expanded from macro 'OS_LOG_STRING'
        _Static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(_str), \
        ^              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:68:17: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:271:9: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_debug'
        os_log_with_type(log, OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:175:9: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_with_type'
        OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT(_os_log_impl, \
        ^
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/trace_base.h:59:47: note: expanded from macro 'OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT'
        OS_LOG_PRAGMA_PUSH OS_LOG_STRING(LOG, _os_fmt_str, fmt); \
                                              ^
.../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:68:46: error: os_log() format argument is not a string constant
                os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, msg);
                                             ^~~
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:271:50: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_debug'
        os_log_with_type(log, OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                                 ^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/log.h:176:55: note: expanded from macro 'os_log_with_type'
                (&__dso_handle, _log_tmp, _type_tmp), format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
                                                      ^~~~~~
In module 'os' imported from .../Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDOSLogger.m:18:
/Applications/Xcode 8.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/include/os/trace_base.h:60:65: note: expanded from macro 'OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT'
        uint8_t _os_fmt_buf[__builtin_os_log_format_buffer_size(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)]; \
                                                                ^~~
```

I've updated cocoa pods, tried this with the last Xcode 8.3.1, cleaned everything, etc... no luck.
What surprises me is that I can't find any discussion of this... apparently I didn't get the message because everyone else either has this working or is using an older tag.

Using tag 3.1.0 works fine, I believe among other things it doesn't have the DDOSLogger included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've managed to fix this, but a similar issue is described here - https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/883

Essentially it was a bug in the CocoaLumberjack that appeared with new version of Xcode and it has already been fixed.